# Float:right; bug in IE7 causes ad to move down, how to fix it?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I am using two ads (160x600) in the right sidebar of my blog. For the ad that is on right side I am using float:right property. Both ads appear side by side in all browsers except in IE 7 where the righ-sided ad floats down.

I will be thankful if you could provide me some good suggestions.

Here is my site address: http://www.shoutpedia.com

Answer (score 0):

If you switch from a `float: auto;` or a `float: left;` to a `float: right;` in IE7 it creates a `<br clear="all" />` effect. The floats need to match. In this case, I'd say you need to make both of the bottom ads `float: right;` and reverse their order. This should work in all browsers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. I reversed the order while keeping the float:right; for the second ad (which is now first in HTML). It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 does not support in `float:right;` and `clear:both;` elements. so you have to use only `float:right;` and `width:100%;` it has get the full width automatic comes down
 after give the `text-align:right;`